# Minimize dependency on other 3rd party library

Tags: design-patterns

I am working on a Mobile Project, and currently use Parse (parse.com), which can help me focus on working with client side. However, I expect my application to grow fast and sooner or later, I will move out of Parse

And because of that situation, I want to write my code with less dependency on Parse as possible or either can make it easy to adapt another Service similar to Parse (even a server I write it myself).

Parse provides ParseUser class, but when I move out of Parse, I will have to write my own User class. And I want to do it now in someway that in the future, when ParseUser class is no longer exists, I can just use the old User class.

If there is any good design pattern for this, please advise!

Comment: I think the design pattern you are looking for is the Provider Model Pattern: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Provider_model

Comment: How come only Microsoft uses that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can make use of interfaces it fairly easy. This is a very minimal example.

```
// Define a proper interface for User instances
interface User() {
    public String getName();
}

// Define the interface that all UserServices must use
interface UserService {
    public User getUser();
}

// Specialized implementation using Parse
class ParseUserService implements UserService {
    public User getUser() {
        return new ParseUser();
    }
}

// Specialized implementation using Other
class OtherUserService implements UserService {
    public User getUser() {
        return new OtherUser();
    }
}

// No need to care about implementation details
class App {
    private UserService userService;

    public void setUserService(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    public void doStuff() {    
        User user = userService.getUser();
        String name = user.getName();
    }
}
```

Comment: This implementation is actually what I want. Since ParseUser is closed, I suppose you want to create another class extend ParseUser and implement User interface?

Comment: That's correct. You also write a wrapper/adapter which is a little more work but more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

One way to minimize dependency on 3d party libraries would be to make a wrapper class around it.
Don't call directly in your application methods from third party libraries, but instead invoke methods defined in your wrapper class.

I don't know what `Parse` does, but lets assume it has a method `parseData()` which you use in your project like this:

```
Parse p = new Parse();
p.parseData();
```

To minimize dependency, create a class `ParseWrapper` that won't do nothing but delegeting the work to `Parse`:

```
public class ParseWrapper{
   Parse p = new Parse();

   //....

   public void parseData(){
       p.parseData(); // Delegate the real work to Parse.
   }
}
```

Now, everywhere in your project use `ParseWrapper` instead of `Parse`:

```
ParseWrapper p = new ParseWrapper();
p.parseData();
```

This way, even if you'll need later to switch from `Parse` to another implementation, you'll have to modify only in one single place - the `ParseWrapper`, the rest of the project will remain untouched.

Comment: This is a simple way, however somehow when I want to use other class for User object, I also have to change the code inside ParseWrapper.

Comment: You could create an interface and then concrete `ParseWrapper` classes. Basically, you can combine my answer with the accepted answer.

Comment: Agree. That will be the best way to do it. Thanks :)